# Can't validate input in modal bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate, bootstrap-modal

hi i want to validated input in bootstrap modal
usually i'm using  something like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="kode" name="kode" placeholder="Kode" required />
```

or using [jquery validating plugins](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) like this

```
$("#formTest").validate({
    rules: {
        kode: "required"
    }
});
```

but none of them working on input inside bootstrap modal
where i'm missing?

---

**@update**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary form-button" id="addNew">Tambah Produk</button> //button to show modal

<form method="post" id="formTest" action="">
    Username : <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" name="username" required>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"></button
</form>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Default</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <form method="post" id="formProduk" action="{{ URL::route('produk.post') }}">
                <div class="row form-group ">
                    <label for="kode_barang" class="control-label col-sm-3">Kode Barang<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kode_barang" name="kode_barang" placeholder="Kode Barang" required />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="saveData">Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in my code above, i have 2 forms `formTest` and `formProduk`
i don't have problem to validate in `formTest` with just `required` property in input

meanwhile in `formProduk`
i already using `required` in input `id=kode_barang`
but after i click button `save`
 it's just parsing without validate to url `produk.post`

Comment: Are you receiving any JavaScript errors? Is your input for your modal created dynamically after the page has been rendered? Or does the input fields in the modal already exist when the page is loaded?

Comment: @Brian i don't see any javascript errors in chrome console...i created input dynamicly...so first user click some button then modal toggle and user type few input

Comment: Show enough code to create a working demonstration of the problem.  Otherwise, there is nothing wrong with the tiny bit of code you've posted.

Comment: you shouldn't use `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="saveData">Save</button>` 2 `type` attributes

Comment: and there is nothing wrong no other reason beside ^^^^^ the validation not working on both forms (on page and in modal) http://jsfiddle.net/m11gaaok/1/ just remove `type="button"` form modal form

Comment: As stated in the previous comments, you cannot have both `type="button"` and `type="submit"` on the same element.  Remove the former.

Comment: @Shehary hahha silly me..thanks for correct it

Comment: Why did you accept the answer below when the root of your problem was the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $("#formTest").unbind().validate({
        rules: {
            kode: "required"
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: still not working..i already adjust this code to my real script like change `formID -> #formProduk` and `kode -> kode_barang` but it's still not validate...please check my update code again...maybe i miss something

Comment: shouldn't the event be `shown.bs.modal` instead `bs.modal.shown`